# dracut-install: ERROR: installing 'sgdisk' dracut: FAILED

Tags: centos, centos8

When i do a Centos 8 routine update from below command.

```
dnf update
```

I got a below error, i have no idea on how to fix this, Any guidance on how to fix this will very valuable.

```
  Running scriptlet: kernel-core-4.18.0-305.3.1.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                            528/529
dracut-install: ERROR: installing 'sgdisk'
dracut: FAILED: /usr/lib/dracut/dracut-install -D /var/tmp/dracut.RTu0To/initramfs -a sgdisk
```

Answer (score 1):

Install **gdisk** package and try again:

```
sudo dnf install gdisk -y
sudo dnf reinstall microcode_ctl kernel-core -y
```

Comment: thanks, solved my issue